# console.log doesn't fire on document scroll reaches to end

Tags: javascript, angular, infinite-scroll

I have a Facebook-like app, where feeds are populated. I have a scroll on my `<body>` but these feeds are in some nested child component `<app-feeds>`. I want to implement an infinite scroll **without** using any library like `ngx-infinite-scroll` or so....
To implement that I'm using `@HostListener()` on the complete document. But console.log('End') is not getting fired when document scroll is reached at the end. Below is my implementation... Somebody, please help me with this.

```
@ViewChild('feedSection') el: ElementRef;

@HostListener('document:scroll', ['$event'])
  onScroll(event: any) {
    const elm = this.el.nativeElement;
    if (elm.offsetHeight + elm.scrollTop >= elm.scrollHeight) {
      console.log('End');
    }
  }
```

My `app-feed` component is

```
<app-home>
   <div #feedSection class="feed-container">
     ...
   </div>
</app-home>
```

Comment: Is onScroll being called?

Comment: Yeah, it is being called, but the problem is with if conditions for sure... I don't knw how should I access the `elm.*` for the `#feedSection` to detect if the page reaches the end

Comment: Can you create a StackBlitz that reproduces the issue please?

Comment: @user184994 here I've created StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cxmogz?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffeeds%2Ffeeds.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got the answer to this question. to solve it without any library of course.
the element itself scrolls and not the whole window. In this case, as the whole window is the scroll I need another approach:

```
@HostListener('document:scroll', ['$event'])
    onScroll(event: any) {
    const boundingBox = document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (boundingBox.height - window.scrollY === window.innerHeight) {
      console.log('End');
    }
  }
```

**PS -** One guy (@alpox) on Gitter suggested me this approach and it works just fine. So I'm posting it here in case anyone else is looking for similar functionality in Angular.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the values for 'offsetHeight', 'scrollHeight' properties using console.log(). In one of my previous project I subtracted offset value of '20px' in order to execute the scroll end condition. It may vary between browsers.